# Why is Mongoose returning "null" continuing to return null regardless of what I do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am able to connect to my MongoDB database and am sure that I am connecting to the correct one. When I try to get a document from the database I always get "null". I am sure that there are documents in the collection as I can see them in Compass.

```
const theschema = new Schema({
    sensor: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

const model = mongoose.model('Sensor', theschema)


model.findOne({}, function(err, data) {
    console.log(data)
})
```

Above is the code I am currently using for this. I'd appreciate any help possible. Thanks! :)

Comment: Have you checked if `err` is defined? Maybe there's some error when you're reading from mongodb.

Comment: What's your collection name and how do you connect to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the problem. The issue was mongoose pluralises collection names therefore it was looking in the wrong collection.

The solution I used was to add this line of code before defining the model
`theschema.set('collection', 'Sensor')`. This force sets the collection so Mongoose doesn't pluralise it

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specifie a condition inside curly brackets. In example:  `Adventure.findOne({ country: 'Croatia' }, function (err, adventure) {});` .

As you can read in [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOne) *Note: conditions is optional, and if conditions is null or undefined, mongoose will send an empty findOne command to MongoDB, which will return an arbitrary document. If you're querying by id, use findById() instead.*

Comment: Ah, you're right about this, because OP is using `findOne()`. In this case, since they're looking for one document in particular, conditions are necessary. But if OP were using `find()`, then `{}` would be a perfectly valid condition, returning all documents.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way in which I can get a random document from the database?

Comment: @JeremyThille I see what you mean. I tried using find() as well and got [] in response. Do you know why this is?

Comment: No, it's indeed supposed to return all documents

Answer (score 0):

You can use to find method if you don't have any query to search for (as per your question) and limit it to some value based on each document size and use case (you can limit it to 1 since you are testing connection it seems)

```
const sensor = mongoose.model('Sensor', theschema)

let query = sensor.find({}).limit(1);
query.exec(function(err, data) {
    console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried that and now I get [] logged in the console. Do you know what the reason is for this?